# How to count possible separations of N items into K clusters?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are to separate N same items into K clusters.

For N=10, K=4 are there 9 ways:

`(7,1,1,1)`, `(6,2,1,1)`, `(5,2,2,1)`, `(4,2,2,2)`, `(5,3,1,1)`, `(4,4,1,1)`, `(4,3,2,1)`, `(3,3,3,1)` and `(3,3,2,2)`.

Is there any formula for this?

Comment: For your specific example: see formula 64 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html). Formula 59 in that link gives you an efficient recursion relation for evaluating the partition number.

Comment: @J.M. That'd be good as an answer :)

Comment: @Zev: Will do, give me a few minutes. (The closed form expression is hella long!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be thought of as a "constrained" [partition number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html). Letting $p(n,k)$ denote the number of ways $n$ can be written as a sum of $k$ terms, MathWorld gives a recurrence relation you can use for computations:

$$p(n,k)=p(n-1,k-1)+p(n-k,k),\quad p(n,0)=0,p(n,n)=1,p(n,k)=0 \text{ if }n < k$$

For the specific case of a partition into four terms, there is a closed form:

$$\begin{align*}p(n,4)&=\frac1{864}\left(-39-27n+18n^2+6n^3-96\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right)\right.+\\&\left.27(1+n)(-1)^n+32\sqrt{3}\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right)\right)+\frac18(-1)^{n/2}(n+1)\bmod 2\end{align*}$$

Closed forms for other values of $k$ are also listed in the link I gave.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to caclulate this, by recursion or by generating functions.

You can find [here](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm) a Java applet (and code) which calculates this and similar questions by recursion.

For generating functions, you want the co-efficient of the $x^{10}$ term in the expansion of $$\frac{x^4}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}.$$

[OEIS A026810](http://oeis.org/A026810) may be of interest.